# Hadoop streaming cannot access jar archive

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am running this hadoop streaming command:

```
/home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar
/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib
/hadoop-*streaming*.jar 
-file audio.py 
-cacheArchive        hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser
  /input/audio/cacheaudiodir.jar#cacheaudiodir 
-input /user/hduser/input/audio -output /user/hduser/output
-mapper audio.py -cmdenv AUDIO_DIR=cacheaudiodir
```

and when I try to refer to 'cacheaudiodir' in my Python mapper I get the error:`No such file or directory`, e.g.:

```
dir_a='cacheaudiodir'
filelist_a = commands.getoutput('/home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls ' + dir_a)
```

How do I point to files in this symlink folder?

Comment: os.path.realpath(dir_a) has the value /tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/filecache/2424241732660840311/cacheaudiodir.jar, so the symlink seems to be pointing to the jar file rather than the decompressed files.

Comment: I've tried a tar.gz instead of a .jar to no avail. ls -alh gives: 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hduser hadoop   84 Aug 28 11:12 cacheaudiodir -> /tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/filecache/545566332614620494/cacheaudiodir.tar.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the cachearchive is untarred locally, NOT in hdfs, so 'hadoop fs -ls' finds nothing whereas 'ls' does.